# wrong media url in wordpress

Tags: uploads, media, http

Having the weirdest issue in a clean Wordpress installation.

The media urls are being written with "hhttp" instead of "http".
so, for example:

```
http://dev.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/...
```

would instead be:

```
hhttp://dev.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/...
```

Tried disabling all plugins and re-uploading images to no avail.

I'm banging my head against the desk trying to figure out why, never had this issue before.

I temporarily fixed the issue by force rewriting all image urls to the correct url and path.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check if the **Uploads** constant is set anywhere, check the output of `wp_upload_dir()` also.